# Hyper-V connection uses slow GPU on Client PC

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Please note, this is NOT about making a Hyper-V connection to a host and utilising the GPU on said host.   I say this, because every search I'm doing for this, thinks this is what I'm trying to achieve.

I've set up a Hyper-V server on my local network. I'm a developer/consultant and I run a VM for every client I have. I sometimes need to run 2-3 VMs and they ideally need 10-14 GB of memory each and thus capping out what my laptop can handle. The CPU on my laptop suffers as well under this load.

So what I did was, I repurposed my last-gen gaming PC (I7, 64 GB ram, 1080 gfx) as a Hyper-V server. I moved some of my VMs to it, [made the necessary configuration](https://tweaks.com/windows/67216/remotely-manage-a-nondomain-hyperv-server-from-windows-10/), and figured I would be all set. I could run a small handful of VMs off of that and thereby offload my laptop.

And here comes the problem. This works, I can connect to my new Hyper-V server fine. I hit an unexpected bottleneck however.

[image]

My laptop Hyper-V connection seems to connect using the onboard (weak) Intel GPU. And just this one connection seems to put that GPU under considerable load - I have noticeable UI lag now, delays when dragging windows around and such. In reality - *my laptop seems more stressed now, running just this one remote connection, than it was when I ran the VM locally*. So the exact opposite result of what I was going for.

Is there a way to make Hyper-V use my better GPU resource?   or is there anything I can do about this?   It makes no sense to me that it taxes my laptop MORE to offload the VM to another machine, than it does to fully run it locally.

I am not trying to game on the remote. The VMs I run are regular Windows 10 environments, running regular (developer) stuff like IIS, SQL Server and so on. There is no performance issue on the server. It is solely my client connection to the host that is giving pain here.

Comment: Try: (1) See if Hyper-V general settings and the VM setting allow GPU specification, (2) Create a new VM from scratch on that computer (if it needs a new template), (3) Install GPU drivers into the VM. General note: There have been reports of Nvidia intentionally not allowing the use of their cards in virtual machines.

Comment: But it's not a problem inside the VM. I don't need the GPU active there. I just need my connection from my laptop to be just a little bit more clever and not clog up my system by using the Intel GPU to render the desktop - or whatever is going on.

Comment: How are you connecting?

Comment: From the Hyper-V manager on my laptop. I've made a connection to the new remote server. Enhanced Session is in use.

Comment: One way to acomplish this is to uninstall the Intel display drivers.  This should make it so the only GPU that can be used is your dGPU.  "my system by using the Intel GPU to render the desktop" - Which desktop exactly?

Comment: The virtual one